# Парсинг Instagram без api на php

Tags: php, парсер, instagram

Не могу получить api instagram так как данная функция не доступна для генерации token.Сейчас загружаю всю страницу file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/missis_luschenko');
получаю количество публикаций и запускаю цикл .И в цикле перебираю массив.
Но проблема в том что публикации подгружаются по 12 динамически .Как мне при достижении 12 вызвать погрузку следующих 12  в цикле php?

Comment: А при чём тут laravel?

Comment: я просто на Lravel пишу.

Comment: Да хоть на зэнде - в вашем вопросе нет никакого кода из laravel.

Comment: Счетчик добавить, не?

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev вы суть вопроса поняли вообще?

Comment: фотки аяксом грузятся, вот и разбирайтесь с этими запросами

Comment: Как вопрос задан, так ответ и получен. Человек хочет в цикле при отработке 12-ти итераций, сделать что-то еще. Цикл заново запустить, получить новые данные, энивэй.

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev вопрос задан вполне нормально, и суть вопроса в том, что картинки грузятся динамически и то как их загрузить. Это явным текстом написано в последних двух предложениях вопроса.

Comment: @teran да согласен....не дочитал

Comment: Сразу скажу не кидайте камнями
Если вы говорите то баг на сайте у них и капчу "Не могу получить api instagram так как данная функция не доступна"
тогда она работает в какой то из старых версий ie

Answer (score 0):

взять chrome-php, и крутить страничку через выполнение `window.scrollBy` пока количество постов не перестанет увеличиваться